# Overlay div with limited scrolling

Tags: html, css

I need to create an overlay div that won't allow the user to click on any page elements but inside the overlay div. The problem is that on mobile devices using landscape orientation, the overlay div needs scrolling.

How can I enable the scrolling only up to the bottom of the overlay div content? I mean, if the page content height is bigger than the overlay div content, the scrolling should be enabled but the overlay div shouldn't be fixed on the top.

Here's a sample of what I need:

```css
.modal-dialog {
opacity: 0.5;
background: #000;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 10;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.modal-content {
background: url('http://dreamatico.com/data_images/mountain/mountain-2.jpg');
height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum...</div>
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the example on **[`JsFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/julianonunes/6yc2n7L2/18/embedded/result/)**.

### UPDATE

I've changed the sample code to be simpler. To run the scenario I'm mentioning you need to open the JsFiddle on your smartphone on landscape mode or open the device emulation on Chrome, choose iPhone 4 in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Give `DIV_1` and `DIV_2` percentage-based `width` and `height`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Ok, Guy. I removed the question mark. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score -1):

For completely hiding the background, position the wrapper div with:

```
position:fixed;
left:0;
right:0;
top:0;
bottom:0;
```

---

To center #DIV_2 you have several options , try `margin: auto`

### [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6yc2n7L2/5/)

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira instead of margin, try centering inner div using `left` `top` properties in combination with `transform: translate`

Comment: You mean by mixing CSS and JS to use transform?

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira no, just with CSS

Comment: how will transform change the position of the overlay without detecting the scroll position via JS? Just to make sure that you understand the problem, the overlay div has a large height and requires vertical scrolling, which doesn't occur as it is using position:fixed

Comment: then `position:fixed` won't work; via JS you could  set a fixed height to body and overflow: hidden ; start from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/6yc2n7L2/26/)